# How to get selected item from 2 separate comboboxes into 3rd combobox and also with itemstatechanged, in java?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have created two comboboxes in netbeans and inserted some items into first combobox and as well into second combobox and when I want to select an item in first and second , both selected values must appear in third combobox . and if I want to change the selection in first and second also it should make the same selection in third combobox,i,e,. the  item status changed .

thanks in advance and  please help me, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which one has precedence?  The first or second combo box?  Does the third combobox contain all the items from the first two?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses.  Also have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Combos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Combos();
    }

    public Combos() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                String[] numbers = new String[10];
                for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                    numbers[index] = String.valueOf(index);
                }
                String[] letters = new String[10];
                for (int index = 0; index < letters.length; index++) {
                    letters[index] = Character.toString((char)(index + 65));
                }

                JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox(numbers);
                JComboBox cb2 = new JComboBox(letters);

                String[] everything = new String[numbers.length + letters.length];
                System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, everything, 0, numbers.length);
                System.arraycopy(letters, 0, everything, numbers.length, letters.length);

                JComboBox cb3 = new JComboBox(everything);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                frame.add(cb1, gbc);
                gbc.gridx++;
                frame.add(cb2, gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                frame.add(cb3, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cb3.setSelectedItem(cb1.getSelectedItem());
                    }
                });
                cb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        cb3.setSelectedItem(cb2.getSelectedItem());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated**

Okay, so basically, for the third `JComboBox`, you need to combine the contents of the other two into a single unified model, for example...

```
String combined[] = new String[numbers.length * letters.length];
int index = 0;
for (int outter = 0; outter < numbers.length; outter++) {
    for (int inner = 0; inner < numbers.length; inner++) {
        combined[index] = numbers[outter] + " " + letters[inner];
        index++;
    }
}
```

Then, when either of the first two change, you can combine the results and use that as the selected item in the third...

```
protected void updateCombinedView() {
    String value = cb1.getSelectedItem() + " " + cb2.getSelectedItem();
    cb3.setSelectedItem(value);
}
```

I still have no idea why, but there you are...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Combos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Combos();
    }

    private JComboBox<String> cb1;
    private JComboBox<String> cb2;
    private JComboBox<String> cb3;

    public Combos() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                String[] numbers = new String[10];
                for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                    numbers[index] = String.valueOf(index);
                }
                String[] letters = new String[10];
                for (int index = 0; index < letters.length; index++) {
                    letters[index] = Character.toString((char) (index + 65));
                }

                String combined[] = new String[numbers.length * letters.length];
                int index = 0;
                for (int outter = 0; outter < numbers.length; outter++) {
                    for (int inner = 0; inner < numbers.length; inner++) {
                        combined[index] = numbers[outter] + " " + letters[inner];
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                cb1 = new JComboBox(numbers);
                cb2 = new JComboBox(letters);

                cb3 = new JComboBox(combined);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                frame.add(cb1, gbc);
                gbc.gridx++;
                frame.add(cb2, gbc);

                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                frame.add(cb3, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        updateCombinedView();
                    }
                });
                cb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        updateCombinedView();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    protected void updateCombinedView() {
        String value = cb1.getSelectedItem() + " " + cb2.getSelectedItem();
        cb3.setSelectedItem(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, but I want to get the only selected items  in the 3rd combo i.e., only 2 items to be displayed from 1st and 2nd respectively, again if any changes in selection of 1st and 2nd items have to displayed in the 3rd combo. but not all only the selected values, i.e., from 1st and 2nd.

Comment: How do you propose to merge them?

Comment: I want to display the elements which I had selected from 2 comboboxes in another i.e., 3rd combobox. 3rd combobox should store only 2 elements i.e., array size should be 2( one element from first combo and another from second combo).

Comment: But, you can't display both elements at the same time, this is my point, either it can display the selected item from the first OR the selected item from the second OR it will have to have a entry for every possible combination of the two...

Comment: it will have to have a entry for every possible combination of the two?  how it is possible, plz explain

Comment: In order for the `JComboBox` to be able show a combination of combobox 1 and combobox 2, it must have a every possible combination of the two, this way, you simply would then be able to use `value1 + value2` (or what ever format you require) and set it as the combobox's selected value.  Unless you do this, I can't see 1- How you would be able to achieve it otherwise and 2- Why you want to do this in the first place...

Comment: Acutally I thought we can store the selected item from 2 comboboxes into an array and we can display that array in third combobox. I can achieve this in android using ArrayAdapter but I can't in java.

Comment: I still don't see how you would combine the two separate arrays down into a single array

Comment: Sir I have tested the code,I need 3rd combobox to be initially empty, when I will select the 1st and 2nd combo box items, only those selected items must display in 3rd combo not all others. and when I want to alter the selection in 1st or in the 2nd combo, the items in 3rd combo box should show now changed items not the older one.

Comment: So, add a blank entry to the list of valid items (or set the selected item to null)